# Jfrog Artifactory Local Filestore to S3 downtime

Tags: artifactory

We are currently running an artifactory server 6.8.12 with a pro license using a local file store with around 400G of artifacts. We want to transition to a s3 file store as jfrog as recently opened up cloud based storage to pro licenses as long as you use one of the big 3 (AWS/Azure/GCP). We are concerned that there will be a large amount of downtime with the migration process described in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/S3+Object+Storage#S3ObjectStorage-AutomaticFilestoreMigration(Recommended) and the manual process described on the same page we know will take a large amount of downtime since it would require moving over 400G of data to s3 which takes awhile.

Does the server run while it is doing the automatic migration after the restart, using the s3 version if it has uploaded it and the local file store version if it has not? Or does the server do a full copy of the artifacts to s3 and then start up, meaning we would have a period of downtime equal to the amount of time it would take for artifactory to upload 400g of data to s3?